# How to Maintain Aspect Ratio with User Input

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a visualizer that shows an image based upon user inputs for height and width. I've got a small issue when the width hits the max-width of the div- I need the height to shrink to keep the aspect ratio of the two dimensions accurate.

```
scss

.display-art {
  height: 30em;
  width: 50em;
}

#art-area {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('link/to/image');
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
html

<div class="display-art">
  <div id="art-area" role="img"></div>
</div>

<input type=" text" id="width1" name="width1" required />
<input type="text" id="height1" name="height1" required />
```

```
js

document.getElementById('height1').addEventListener('keyup', changeSize);
document.getElementById('width1').addEventListener('keyup', changeSize);

function changeSize() {
  const height = document.getElementById('height1').value;
  const width = document.getElementById('width1').value;
  const art_area = document.getElementById('art-area');

  setTimeout(() => {
    art_area.style.height = `${height}px`;
    art_area.style.width = `${width}px`;
  }, 250);
}
```

Basically, I need a way to determine when `width` is equal to the max-width of `#art-area` and adjust `height` to keep the aspect ratio the same. I think I need to use JS to handle it, but I have no ideas of how to compare the `width` and `max-width` to get the result I need.

(The reason I'm using a `div` with the `role=img` is that I need to toggle a specific overlay on the image. It doesn't work correctly when I switch that `div` to an `img`.)

Does anybody have any ideas?